# Jquery Ajax Post is calling wrong action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I will bring code first.

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult VideoList(int page)
    {
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveWindowWidth(string width)
    {
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
var width = $("#Window").width();

$.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Video/SaveWindowWidth',
        async: "true",
        data: { "width": width },
        dataType: 'text json',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        success: function (data, status)
        {
            if (data)
            {
                alert(data.status);
            }
        },
        error: function (data, status)
        {
            if (data)
            {
                alert(data.status);
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Routes:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            "Home", // Route name
            "Home", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "BookPage", // Route name
            "BookPage/{page}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Book", action = "Page" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "BlogMember", // Route name
            "BlogMember/{id}/{page}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Blog", action = "Member" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "BlogPost", // Route name
            "BlogPost/{id}/{page}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Blog", action = "Post" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "BlogPage", // Route name
            "BlogPage/{page}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Blog", action = "Page" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "BlogTag", // Route name
            "BlogTag/{tag}/{page}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Blog", action = "Tag" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "NewBlogPostComment", // Route name
            "NewBlogPostComment", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Blog", action = "NewBlogPostComment" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "NewBlogPost", // Route name
            "NewBlogPost", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Blog", action = "NewBlogPost" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "EditBlogPost", // Route name
            "EditBlogPost/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Blog", action = "EditBlogPost" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Account", // Route name
            "Account", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Account", action = "Update" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "LogOff", // Route name
            "LogOff", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOff" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "LogOn", // Route name
            "LogOn", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Register", // Route name
            "Register", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Account", action = "Register" }
        );

        //routes.MapRoute(
        //    "About", // Route name
        //    "About", // URL with parameters
        //    new { controller = "Home", action = "About" }
        //);

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Contact", // Route name
            "Contact", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "UnderConstruction", // Route name
            "UnderConstruction", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "UnderConstruction" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "DisableBlogComment", // Route name
            "DisableBlogComment/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Blog", action = "DisableBlogComment" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "DisableAllMemberBlogComments", // Route name
            "DisableAllMemberBlogComments/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Blog", action = "DisableAllMemberBlogComments" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "DisableVideoComment", // Route name
            "DisableVideoComment/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Video", action = "DisableVideoComment" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "DisableAllMemberVideoComments", // Route name
            "DisableAllMemberVideoComments/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Video", action = "DisableAllMemberVideoComments" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "DisableMember", // Route name
            "DisableMember/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Member", action = "DisableMember" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "NewPost", // Route name
            "NewPost", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Blog", action = "NewPost" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "InactiveBlogPosts", // Route name
            "InactiveBlogPosts/{page}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Blog", action = "InactiveBlogPosts" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "InactiveBlogComments", // Route name
            "InactiveBlogComments/{page}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Blog", action = "InactiveBlogComments" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "InactiveVideoComments", // Route name
            "InactiveVideoComments/{page}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Video", action = "InactiveVideoComments" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "EditHomePage", // Route name
            "EditHomePage", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "EditHomePage" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "EditAboutPage", // Route name
            "EditAboutPage", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "EditAboutPage" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Newsletter", // Route name
            "Newsletter", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Newsletter", action = "Newsletter" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "RegisterNewVideo", // Route name
            "RegisterNewVideo", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Video", action = "RegisterNewVideo" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Members", // Route name
            "Members/{page}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Member", action = "MemberList" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "EditMember", // Route name
            "EditMember/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Member", action = "EditMember" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "AppSettings", // Route name
            "AppSettings", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Utility", action = "AppSettings" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "AudioBookPage", // Route name
            "AudioBookPage/{page}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Book", action = "AudioBookPage" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "IPBlocked", // Route name
            "IPBlocked", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Utility", action = "IPBlocked" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "LiveTV", // Route name
            "LiveTV", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "LiveTV", action = "LiveTV" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "VideoPlayer", // Route name
            "VideoPlayer/{id}/{page}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Video", action = "VideoPlayer" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Video", // Route name
            "Video/{page}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Video", action = "VideoList" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "NewVideoComment", // Route name
            "NewVideoComment", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Video", action = "NewVideoComment" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Music", // Route name
            "Music", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Music", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "RootsCompilationOne", // Route name
            "Music/RootsCompilationOne", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Music", action = "RootsCompilationOne" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "UnityIsStrength", // Route name
            "Music/UnityIsStrength", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Music", action = "UnityIsStrength" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "FileUpload", // Route name
            "FileUpload", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Utility", action = "FileUpload" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "PageUnavailable", // Route name
            "PageUnavailable", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Utility", action = "PageUnavailable" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "VideoGrid", // Route name
            "VideoGrid/{page}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Video", action = "VideoGrid" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "EditVideo", // Route name
            "EditVideo/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Video", action = "EditVideo" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "CopyVideo", // Route name
            "CopyVideo/{id}/{page}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Video", action = "CopyVideo" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "DeleteIPLogs", // Route name
            "DeleteIPLogs/{ip}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Utility", action = "DeleteIPLogs" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "SaveWindowWidth", // Route name
            "SaveWindowWidth/{width}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Video", action = "SaveWindowWidth" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "FacebookLikes", // Route name
            "FacebookLikes", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Utility", action = "FacebookLikes" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Problem that ajax tries to call VideoList method. I see it when read response:

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'page' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult VideoList(Int32)'

I have heard somewhere that it may be something wrong with routes, so I posted them here as well.
I would appreciate your help

Regards
Mariusz

Comment: I forgotten to add. This same problem happens when trying to use @Ajax.RouteLink from within the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your video route is not well configured. MVC tries to get the controller and action from each url to figure out required method from appropriate controller. And in your case, it always gets same values VideoController.VideoList():

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Video", // Route name
            "Video/{page}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Video", action = "VideoList" }
        );
```

If you change your route to this, everything will be ok:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Video", // Route name
            "Video/{action}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Video", action = "VideoList" }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use string to store value as URL is not a best practice.

I do something like this.

View

```
@Html.Hidden("getVideoUrl", Url.Action("SaveWindowWidth", "Video"))
```

JS

```
   var url = $("#getVideoUrl").val();
    $.post(url, data: { "width": width },      
        success: function (data, status)
        {
            if (data)
            {
                alert(data.status);
            }
        },
        error: function (data, status)
        {
            if (data)
            {
                alert(data.status);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Very nice suggestion. Will start using it this way.
This approach is much more safer as doesn't create dependency. Nice.

Still new to MVC :-)

Answer (score 1):

Dima has identified the issue, though his solution wouldn't quite work for you. Your routes are configured such that when requesting a url `Video/SaveWindowWidth`, call the action `VideoList` on the controller `Video` with the parameter `page` set to `SaveWindowWidth`. Clearly that is not what you wanted.

ASP.Net MVC will execute the first route that matches. Which is why it's important to include all specific routes first.

One of the ways to fix this is to re-write your routes such that certain API routes are configured above your generic pretty routes. To do so, you would need to mention every single combination before any pretty url.

For example,

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "SaveWindowWidthForVideo", // Route name
        "Video/SaveWindowWidth",
        new { controller = "Video", action = "SaveWindowWidth" }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
        "SaveWindowHeightForVideo", // Route name
        "Video/SaveWindowHeight",
        new { controller = "Video", action = "SaveWindowHeight" }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
        "SaveWindowSomethingElseForVideo", // Route name
        "Video/SaveWindowHeight",
        new { controller = "Video", action = "SaveWindowSomethingElseForVideo" }
    );

// etc etc      

// your remaining pretty urls
routes.MapRoute(
        "Video", // Route name
        "Video/{page}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Video", action = "VideoList" }
    );
```

I don't prefer to do that, as it can get rather cumbersome very easily.

The solution I prefer is to distinguish between my pretty url routes and my ajax API routes by adding the word `api` in the url.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "ApiCallsForVideo", // Route name
        "api/video/{action}",
        new { controller = "Video" }
    );

// or

routes.MapRoute(
        "ApiCalls", // Route name
        "api/{controller}/{action}"
    );



// etc etc      

routes.MapRoute(
        "Video", // Route name
        "Video/{page}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Video", action = "VideoList" }
    );
```

This obviously involves modifying your ajax calls to include the word `api`.

Comment: Very nice. Learned a lot from it and will implement. Dimas help worked not directly but made me aware I need to reconfigure routes.

Thanks for this advice.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you need to add parameter in route then only your ajax will call that method with parameter. Now whats happening is ur ajax is calling that particular methot but you 've not mentioned in route that to allow parameter

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Video", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Video", action = "VideoList", width= UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

then only ur parameter can be passed to ur controller.
and calling url will look like this

```
 url: '/Video/SaveWindowWidth'+width,
```

or

```
url: '/Video/SaveWindowWidth?width=' + width,
```

its working fine for me!

Hope it helps